# Using Ghostscript to convert multi-page PDF into single JPG?

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I know Ghostscript can convert PDFs to JPGs, and in the case of a multi-page PDF, can rip each page to an individual JPG. But is it possible to have it rip them to one JPG, so that the pages are pasted below each other, e.g. the top half of the JPG is page 1, the bottom half is page 2? Or do I have to use another program (and can ImageMagick do this?) to combine the JPG pages into one image?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to convert each PDF page into a single JPG file (Ghostscript can do that).

Then stitch together the resulting JPG files using another program ([ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) or [GraphicsMagic](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/montage.html) can do that using their `montage` sub-commands).

I'm not aware of any software which can do that in one go.

***PDF-to-JPG conversion (with Ghostscript):***
You'll want to make sure that you get the best possible result. So make sure you tweak the commandline options so they work for you. ***I***'d start with this:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
    -dBATCH ^
    -dNOPAUSE ^
    -dSAFER ^
    -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
    -dJPEGQ=95 ^
    -r600x600 ^
    -sOutputFile=c:/path/to/jpeg-dir/pdffile-%03d.jpeg ^
    c:/path/to/pdffile.pdf
```

This will create JPGs called *pdffile-001.jpeg*, *pdffile-002.jpg* etc. The parameter *-dJPEGQ=95" sets "JPEG Quality" to 95%. It uses a resolution of "600x600 dpi". You may need to additionally control the pagesize of the resulting JPGs in case your Ghostscript's default doesn't fit your needs:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
    -dBATCH ^
    -dNOPAUSE ^
    -dSAFER ^
    -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
    -dJPEGQ=95 ^
    -r600x600 ^
    -dPDFFitPage ^
    -dFIXEDMEDIA ^
    -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=800 ^
    -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=600 ^
    -sOutputFile=c:/path/to/jpeg-dir/pdffile-%03d.jpeg ^
    c:/path/to/pdffile.pdf
```

or

```
gswin32c.exe ^
    -dBATCH ^
    -dNOPAUSE ^
    -dSAFER ^
    -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
    -dJPEGQ=95 ^
    -r600x600 ^
    -dPDFFitPage ^
    -dFIXEDMEDIA ^
    -sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a4 ^
    -sOutputFile=c:/path/to/jpeg-dir/pdffile-%03d.jpeg ^
    c:/path/to/pdffile.pdf
```

***multiple-to-single-JPG-stitching with `montage` (ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick):***
The `montage` command (used in this example is ImageMagick) allows you to control the tiling pattern. If you use e.g. `-tile 4x3` you'd get this imposition layout:

```
1  2  3  4    
5  6  7  8    
9 10 11 12
```

You could use this command to stitch together 12 individual JPGs into one:

```
montage ^
    -border 0  ^
    -tile 4x3  ^
    c:/path/to/jpeg-dir/pdffile-*.jpeg  ^
    c:/path/to/final.jpg
```

Of course, `montage` has many dozen of additional parameters which allow you to determine background, spacing, offsets, decoration, labels, rotation, cropping, caption etc. for the input and the resulting JPG.

---

***EDIT:*** (I had wanted to give this hint already in my original answer, but forgot.) `montage` by default will use tile sizes of 120x120 pixels. If you want to keep the original page sizes for each tile, you have to add `-geometry` to the commandline. Assuming you had *A4* (=595x852 pt) pages in your PDF, and you want to keep this, but also add a spacing of 11pt to the horizontal and 22 pt to the vertical direction of the tiling (plus 4pt strong gray border/frame lines around each tile), do this:

```
montage ^
    -border 4 ^
    -tile 4x3 ^
    -geometry 595x842+11+22 ^
    c:/path/to/jpeg-dir/pdffile-*.jpeg ^
    c:/path/to/final.jpg
```

---

***EDIT 2:*** (Missed still another important hint.) If you do not want to lose the good image quality during the stitching/montage process, which your PDF-to-JPG conversion had created, then also add the `-quality 100` parameter to your commandline like this:

```
montage ^
    -border 4 ^
    -tile 4x3 ^
    -geometry 595x842+11+22 ^
    -quality 100 ^
    c:/path/to/jpeg-dir/pdffile-*.jpeg ^
    c:/path/to/final.jpg
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't see geometry param in ImageMagick 6.9.9. Also, the image quality of combined image is still crappy, I literally can't read a word from it.

Answer (score 2):

Since ImageMagick has support for GhostScript built in, you can do the whole thing in one go:

```
montage -tile 5 thispdfis25pages.pdf tiledoverview.jpg
```

which will take every page and create one long jpeg of them end-to-end.

Comment: But this will ***NOT*** give you high quality JPG, because it will use Ghostscript with its default settings (and these are quite shi..y for JPG output). Doing it in 2 steps (and checking your JPG pages first) gives you optimal control, and it also gives you rather good JPG output).

Comment: You can change the Ghostscript settings by using ImageMagick's -density setting for the PDF and get results that are as good.  Don't knock IM if you're not aware of how to use its options.

Comment: k.: Hey, I didn't knock ImageMagick. And I know how to use its options, even with applying ICC color profiles... But you cannot pass **all** Ghostscript options to montage. My comment referred to your suggested command, which did **not** mention `-density`.

Comment: Incidentally, I read elsewhere on SO that ImageMagick internally converts from PDF to PS and then PS to PNG when you invoke it this way, so that's another reason not to do it this way (two conversions=>lower quality and slower).