# How do I batch extract first page of multiple pdfs

Tags: pdf, batch, ghostscript

I know there is another thread with many answers for this question; however, I am a newbie and a lot of that was gibberish to me. I am trying to learn though:)

Anyway, I've installed ghostscript and tried to run it a few times using this script

```
for file in *.pdf ; do gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
         -sOutputFile="${file%.pdf}-page1.pdf" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "$file" ;
```

I got that script from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/207414/extract-first-page-from-multiple-pdfs).

I didn't really know where to put the directory name that I wanted the program to batch extract from nor the output filename, and or the output director.  I realize this is basic stuff for most you but if anyone could help me out you'd be saving me probably years of work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory where the PDF files reside is the current directory, since `for files in *.pdf ; ...` does not specify a directory path for the matching files.

The output file is formed from `"$file"` with the `bash` expansion `"${file%.pdf}-page1.pdf"`, which deletes `.pdf` from the end of the file name and replaces it with `-page1.pdf`, so that, for example, `report.pdf` generates the output file `report-page1.pdf` in the same directory.

You can prepend a directory path in the `for` clause, eg `for files in SourceDir/*.pdf ; ...`

You can change the replacement string; or you can prepend a directory, though the substitution becomes more complex if you use a directory path in the `for` clause.

You should read up on **Parameter Expansion** in the `bash` manual.